# Text based adventure challenge issues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new at coding and I've been trying this **text-based adventure game**. I keep running into syntax error and I don't seem to know how to solve this. Any suggestions on where I could have gone wrong would go a long way to helping.

```
    def play_again():
        print("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)")
        answer = input(">")
        if answer == "y":
            play_again()
        else:
            exit()
    
    def game_over(reason):
        print("\n", reason)
        print("Game Over!!!")
    
        play_again()
    
    def diamond_room():
        print("\nYou are now in the room filled with diamonds")
        print("what would you like to do?")
        print("1) pack all the diamonds")
        print("2) Go through the door")
        answer = input(">")
        
        if answer == "1":
            game_over("The building collapsed bcos the diamonds were cursed!")
        elif answer == "2":
            print("You Win!!!")
            play_again()
        else:
            game_over("Invalid prompt!")
    
    
    def monster_room():
        print("\nYou are now in the room of a monster")
        print("The monster is sleeping and you have 2 choices")
        print("1) Go through the door silently")
        print("2) Kill the monster and show your courage")
        answer = input(">")
    
        if answer == "1":
            diamond_room()
        elif answer == "2":
            game_over("You are killed")
        else:
            game_over("Invalid prompt")
    
    
    def bear_room():
        print("\nThere's a bear in here!")
        print("The bear is eating tasty honey")
        print("what would you like to do?")
        print("1) Take the honey")
        print("2) Taunt the bear!")
        answer = input(">").lower()
    
        if answer == "1":
            game_over("The bear killed you!!!")
        elif answer == "2":
            print("The bear moved from the door, you can now go through!")
            diamond_room()
        else:
            game_over("Invalid prompt")
    
    
    def start():
        print("Do you want to play my game?")
        answer = input(">").lower()
    
        if answer == "y":
            print("\nyou're standing in a dark room")
            print("you have 2 options, choose l or r")
            answer == input(">")
    
        if answer == "l":
            bear_room()
        elif answer == "r":
            monster_room()
        else:
            game_over("Invalid prompt!")
            
    start()
```

it keeps popping error and i cant detect where the error is coming from.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

1. Assertion instead of Assignment.
2. Calling the wrong function.

For 1. You have

```
def start():
    print("Do you want to play my game?")
    answer = input(">").lower()

    if answer == "y":
        print("\nyou're standing in a dark room")
        print("you have 2 options, choose l or r")
        answer == input(">")

    if answer == "l":
        bear_room()
    elif answer == "r":
        monster_room()
    else:
        game_over("Invalid prompt!")
```

You should uuse `answer = input(">")` and not `answer ==`.

For 2. You have

```
def play_again():
    print("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)")
    answer = input(">")
    if answer == "y":
        play_again()
    else:
        exit()
```

You should call `start` not `play_again`

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code, you should change you last line:

```
if answer == "y":
   print("\nyou're standing in a dark room")
   print("you have 2 options, choose l or r")
   answer == input(">")
```

to answer = input(">").lower()

1. use = to assign a value to a variable, and use == to check the similarity(ex. in an if)
2. it is better to make the user input to lower case as other parts of your code, because in next lines of you've checked its value in an if condition with lower case (r and l).

3)another problem is that in def play_again(): you have to call start() function, sth like this:

```
        print("\nDo you want to play again? (y/n)")
        answer = input(">")
        if answer == "y":
            start()
```